# Ionic Vue: How do I preselect ion-select with data binding?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, select

I have this ionic vue selection:

```
<template>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Typ</ion-label>
    <ion-select interface="action-sheet" value="expense">
      <ion-select-option value="expense" selected>Expense</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="income">Income</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</template>

<script>
import { IonItem, IonLabel, IonSelect, IonSelectOption } from "@ionic/vue";
export default {
  components: { IonItem, IonLabel, IonSelect, IonSelectOption },
}
</script>
```

So far it works fine; I can preselect the expense option with `value="expense"`:

[image]

However, when I add data binding, the pre-selection doesn't work anymore:

```
<template>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Typ</ion-label>
    <ion-select interface="action-sheet" value="expense" v-model="selectedCategoryType">
      <ion-select-option value="expense" selected>Expense</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="income">Income</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</template>

<script>
import { IonItem, IonLabel, IonSelect, IonSelectOption } from "@ionic/vue";
export default {
  components: { IonItem, IonLabel, IonSelect, IonSelectOption },
  computed: {selectedCategoryType: ""}
}
</script>
```

[image]

Why is that and how do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Typ</ion-label>
    <ion-select interface="action-sheet" v-model="selectedCategoryType">
      <ion-select-option value="expense" selected>Expense</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="income">Income</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</template>

<script>
import { IonItem, IonLabel, IonSelect, IonSelectOption } from "@ionic/vue";
export default {
  components: { IonItem, IonLabel, IonSelect, IonSelectOption },
  setup(){
    const selectedCategoryType = ref<any>("");

    // set default value here
    selectedCategoryType.value = "expense"

    return { selectedCategoryType }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For me this doesn't work; it says that ref and any are not defined. Maybe that's not vue?

Comment: put your code in a project or up on codesandbox

Comment: I didnt manage to put it on codesandbox, but I managed to fix the problem with `data() {return {selectedCategoryType: "expense",}}`